# What does it mean to encrypt with a public key?

Tags: security, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I've heard lots of public key theory, but I've never really understood how you can encrypt something that can be decrypted with a private key that you don't have.

How does encrypting a message with a public key make it so that only the person with the corresponding private key associated with that key can decrypt it?

Comment: Looks like the best duplicate for this is on another site: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/292/how-does-asymmetric-encryption-work. This will probably be closed as off topic for this site as it's not specifically about programming encryption.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. A question like this is much better suited for [crypto.se]. Although a duplicate probably exists.

Comment: @PatrickM I found the answer and video to be very helpful. Perhaps you could just move this over to the Cryptography section. When I first started, the question, I had planned to ask how to implement such a feature in code, but as I typed, I realized I really just wanted to know how it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXB-V_Keiu8) by Youtube channel Art of the Problem does a good job of explaining it conceptually, before getting into the exact details of how the RSA algorithm implements it.

If you think of encryption as use of a lock and key to secure information, then standard shared-key encryption involves both you and your collaborator holding onto the same key. When you send a message, you take your message, shut it inside a locked box by using your key, then send the box to the recipient who opens it with a copy of the key that you have.

In public-private key encryption, you don't give out copies of your key; you keep your key private. Instead, you give out instructions on how to build a lock that only your key can open. You give this out to anyone who asks for it. They are responsible for building the lock and using it to secure their information before sending it back to you. If they do it correctly, then the lock they've built opens perfectly when you put your private key in it.

A different way to think about the encryption step is that you actually hand out copies of your lock to anyone who wants to send you a message. They can take this lock, slap it on their message and no one can open it to read the contents without the key - not even the original sender! This would be very expensive to do with physical locks, but is very easy to do digitally.

Public-private encryption relies on a [One-way function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function) (more correctly, a certain type of one-way function called a [trapdoor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function)), a mathematical formula that is easy to compute, but hard to find the inputs if you only have the output. Analogously, you have a lock design such that it is easy to construct from a set of instructions, but hard to reverse engineer without seeing the actual key that fits the lock.

I tend to also think about this part in terms of tying knots. It's very easy to take a series of steps to tie a rope in knots. Even know what you did and in what order, some times it's impossible to reverse the order of the steps to undo the knot. Either you've put in a slip somewhere, or you need to get your secret knot-untying key to release the rope. (Hint: the secret knot untying key is a knife. Count your fingers when you're done.)

Answer (score 2):

Encryption keys come in a public/private pair. The private is closely held by the owner, but the public can be passed around to those who need to encrypt something in order to send it to the owner.

Something that has been encrypted by the public key can only be decrypted with the private key as it contains more details used by the encrypt/decrypt routines.

While this may not provide the technical details you may be looking for, hopefully it helps shed some light on the relationship between the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it like this:

> A message from Person B is being delivered to only Person A. Person A
>   has the key (Private Key) to open the Chest (Public Key) and read the
>   message. At this point, Person A can respond to the message and place
>   it back in the Chest (Public Key) and redeliver to Person B. Person B
>   can now use their key (Private Key of their own) to read the message in the Chest (Public Key)

Hopefully this analogy will help.